# floating with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, validation

I'm doing a validation in javascript and need to create a floating div for each field when submitting the form

I'm using `blur` to check the field, but do not know how to create a floating div

would be as in the diagram below

someone has an idea?

> [field 1] [float error message]
>
> [field 2] [float error message]
>
> [field 3] [float error message]

Comment: Also, please avoid tagging your question with plugins you're not using... removed superfluous tag-spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the floating div after the field that was blur'd like so

```
$('input[type=text]').blur(function() {
  // do your validation
  if (error) {
    $('<p>')
      .text('Validation Error: '+error)
      .css('float', 'left')
      .insertAfter(this);
  }
});
```

IMHO it's best to keep all styling in CSS. I would personally replace the ".css()" call with ".addClass()", then setup a style rule that floated the error messages. If this approach was used, and the fields were originally wrapped like this:

```
<div class="field">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder...>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder...>
</div>
...
```

Then clearing the validation would be as simple as:

```
$(this).siblings('.validation-error').remove();
```

Comment: only issue with this approach is how does the op remove the validation error when the error is corrected?

Comment: Indeed, as will removal element?

Comment: Expanded my answer to include this scenario. It wasn't part of the question it is a good thing to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for technique, then any in-line element after the field element will do the trick. Ex.

```
<input type="text" name="firstName"><span>show on error</span><br />
<input type="text" name="lastName"><span>show on error</span><br />
<input type="text" name="empId"><span>show on error</span><br />
```

make these errors hidden initially (through styles) and show/hide them by script on validation as,

```
if(err_cond_of_elem) 
    $(elem).next().show(); 
else 
    $(elem).next().hide();
```

**Edit:**

If your errors are dynamic then you can add them by `.html()` metod of JQuery

```
$(elem).next().html(custom_err_message).show();
```

Comment: seems like you and i agree on approach.  i like your thinking, as i think it's always best to load the dom with needed markup and not do complicated dom manipulation for something this easy. i also added some help tips for the css approach. but overall, i think we agree.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided any markup or code, I'll provide a pattern for my response.
Here's how I would do this.

1.) Create your form with text inputs and error message in your markup.  So the markup could be something like:

```
<form id="whatever">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" id="1" value=""/><div id="error1">text for error 1</div>
<input type="text" id="2" value=""/><div id="error2">text for error 2</div>
<input type="text" id="3" value=""/><div id="error3">text for error 3</div>
</fieldset>
..
..
</form>
```

2.) Create your css to float text inputs left.  The error divs could be set as display:none, float:left;  This would make sure error messages are hidden when page loads and float properly. Also, my philosophy is to let HTML do HTML and CSS do CSS and JS do JS.  So rather than manipulating the dom with jquery, just place markup and content on your page and use css to handle initial visibility and positioning. No need to do that with js.

3.) Then, in your method to check input values on blur, if the validation detects an error, all you have to do is show the corresponding error with .show().  Then as the user works to correct the input and passes your validation check, set the corresponding error to .hide().